# How to login with recently registered user to openfire in ios?

Tags: ios, authentication, xmpp, openfire

I can't login with my newly registered user .But after 3 times of attempt at third time I am able to login .
LOG OUTPUT for first two times :`RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>`

After login Log Output is :

```
 SEND: <?xml version='1.0'?>
SEND: <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='www.demoseocousa.com'>
RECV:<stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="www.demoseocousa.com" id="60a9c5ba" stream1:lang="en" version="1.0"/>
```

But when I check it at server it is already registered.
Can anyone please help me I am in a very difficult situation as this is new for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a cache issue, you should manually empty users cache in the admin console. Or you can set custom maxLifetime for user list.
This is cache doc [openfire cache](https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1673)

And set User custom parameters

Comment: thanks for answer but how to do that can you give me some instructions or link than it will be more beneficial   .

Comment: i have followed this  but did not work.    Admin Console > Server > Server Manager > Cache Summary page>users>check it >clear selected